# Azure Search only returns an element

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cognitive-search

We have an azure search index that returns only one element despite having 3 matches.

However Azure Search only returns the first one. We would need the three matches returned as they belong to different parent entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like only one of the 3 documents got indexed. It looks like they all have the same document ID (conferenceId), which means each row overwrote the previous one during indexing.  Do you have a unique value in your rowset that you can use as a document ID?

Answer (score 1):

@user22673702 is correct. All you have to do is either change the key from conference id to SurveyXid (or some other unique value) or change the currenct conference id and make it unique.

> "key" Unique identifier for documents within the index. Exactly one
> field must be chosen as the key field and it must be of type
> Edm.String."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index#field-attributes